# How to Display .flv Video on HTML 5

Tags: html

Is it possible to display a .flv video on HTML 5 (in WAMP Localhost)? I already read and used codes from this article but it doesn't work for me!
http://gettingsoftware.posterous.com/html5flash-using-html5-video-and-audio-right

Thanks,

Comment: Well, considering FLV stands for FLASH VIDEO, it might be impossible to do it without flash.  It's a horrible inefficient format anyway, try converting it to a more sensible one (mp4 is probably a good bet).  You can download many tools that can perform this conversion, such as ffmpeg, a free command line tool with support for pretty much everything ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only supported formats are: Ogg Theora, H.264, WebM VP8.

And you'll need to check browser support for them as well.

[Give it a read.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support)

Comment: if you go H.264, WebM VP8 only you should be safe for all major browsers, and youl save bout 1/3 on your disk